# filter functions multiple times

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have the following representative spreadsheet:

[image]

I am wanting to list the documents by using Xs like so:

[image]

So far, I have been able to get "(A) Document 1" by using formula

=JOIN(" ",,FILTER(F3:G4,F5:G5="X"))

But that does not work if I put a x in "(B) Document 1" or if I put an x in multiple columns.

How can one accomplish listing documents using Xs using a formula?

Comment: Please reflect what software you are using and remove the other tag. The two are different, especially when it comes to these functions.

Comment: My solution using excel formula is not perfect and it requires you to modify the second row (showing document name) to un-merge the cells and show the document name in each column. Alternatively, you can use **PowerQuery** but each time when you change the `x` mark, you will need to refresh the data to have an updated list of document names. I do not have a solution using the Google-Sheets formula.

Comment: fixed tag. I inadvertently added excel BUT this is Q is for google sheets.